Which movie is it where a speech giver gets shot during the middle of the speech through a column?
I remember that during the investigations after the scene, it was discovered that there were two shooters from two different angles because the investigators put straws or something through the two bullet holes.
This was an English/American movie, by a major Hollywood production company. This movie was not very recent, but not very old either, maybe shot within the past 10 years? It is older than 4 years for sure though.
Details:

It might have been a spy movie
The scene happened in a European country but the characters spoke english
One of the shooters was shooting through a window in a hotel
The other shooter was on the roof of the building (not sure though)
I think the roof shooter was pursued afterwards
The speech giver was a politician or had some relations with politics
It was in front of a large crowd and I believe the scene that the speech giver was shot was shown live on the news (in the movie)
The speech giver was on a large stage with a red background


Welcome to the community. You may have more helpful information than you realize. If you know, please also describe when you saw it, in what language, country and year of production, plot locale, names of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Check out The Jackal with Bruce Willis, it had a similar scene: http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0119395/

The movie is The International (2009).
Clive Owen and Naomi Watts are the two Interpol agents who investigate the site of the shooting.
Detailed plot description for the movie on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_International_(2009_film)

"Salinger's and Whitman's investigation takes them from Berlin to
  Milan, where the IBBC assassinates Umberto Calvini, an arms
  manufacturer who is an Italian prime ministerial candidate. The bank's
  assassin diverts suspicion to a local assassin with political
  connections, who is promptly killed by a corrupt policeman. Salinger
  and Whitman get a lead on the second assassin, but the corrupt
  policeman shows up again and orders them out of the country. At the
  airport they are able to check the security camera footage for clues
  on the whereabouts on the bank's assassin, and follow a suspect to New
  York City."

The first sniper shoots through a hole in a window. Unbeknownst to him, there is a second, "real" sniper who shoots from a rooftop. The first sniper is only a pawn, he is used as a decoy, shortly after the assassination he is killed. The second sniper carries out the assasination from the rooftop, he escapes and goes back to New York (where later he meets his end during an epic shootout in the Guggenheim Museum).
Here is a clip which shows the assassination:



You can watch the movie here (with French dubbing):



At the 0:39:00 mark starts the part where the two Interpol agents, together with a local police detective, go back to the scene of the political rally and Owen and Watts investigate the scene of the assassination.
Here are two shots of the scene investigation: 
Bullet holes in the support column

Sticks in the bullet holes

